# Regarding "Migration request to all related Team Drives fields"

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to migrate to Drives resource collection to replace the “Team Drives” resource collection as described [Upcoming changes to the Google Drive API and Google Picker API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api#jump-content)

> Next, we’re introducing a new Drive API resource collection, called “Drives,” to replace the “Team Drives” resource collection. This new resource collection can help you create, delete, get, list and update your shared drives, and features all the same fields, resources and available methods as the “Team Drives” resource collection. If you have been using the “Team Drives” resource collection in your applications, consider migrating as soon as possible as all related fields for Drive API , Drive Activity API and Google Picker API, will no longer be supported starting June 1, 2020.

I have a scenario where in, my application might still use 
`driveService.TeamDrives.list` instead of `driveService.Drives.list`. In that scenario, I would like to know whether the request using `driveService.TeamDrives.list` still succeeds?

Comment: The documentation is clear about not using Teamdrives anymore, so I recommend you to update your code, otherwise you are risking the functionality of your script.